# Ubuntu trunk forwarding or bridging between two physical linux interfaces eth0 and eth1 - OpenvSwitch or etc

Tags: networking, ubuntu, port-forwarding, switch, bridge

I want to learn, if it is possible? and how to configure, a ARM based Ubuntu Server system as a bridge between two physical network interfaces to pass all Vlan trunk traffic through eth0 and eth1.

What i want to achieve is:

[image]

I don't want the network address changes on the switches effects the system to operate.

I want the Ubuntu server to operate as a network switch, not as a router.

I want all packets from one Switch's trunk port to flow to other Switch's trunk port without loosing any packet or service, through ARM based Ubuntu Server's Physical Network interfaces.

I installed OpenvSwitch to Ubuntu Server and try to achieve it but i still have no success to manage to do it.

Any method is highly appreciated!

I do not have any security concerns and all IPTABLE rules can be deleted or accepted. (I don't know how to do that and ufw is not installed on the system.)

I would be very happy if someone can help me with the situation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about OpenvSwitch, but what you are doing is entirely practical.

What you want to do is bridge eth0 and eth1

This can be done a number of ways depending on how networking is configured, e.g.

```
ip link add br0 type bridge
ip link set eth0 master br0
ip link set eth1 master br0
ip link set br0 up
```

On older systems you will want the bridge-utils package installed.  You can then use brctl to create a bridge - something along the lines of

```
brctl addbr br0         # Create a bridge interface
brctl addif br0 eth0
brctl addif br0 eth1
ifconfig br0 up
```

You will then have a new interface br0, and you should assign IP addresses etc to this.  Underneath it will have a virtual switch comprising eth0 and eth1.

(I know you said you are not worried about security - just FYI) This happens beneath the level that iptables operates at.  nftables provides firewalling at this level)

https://www.tecmint.com/create-network-bridge-in-ubuntu/ has details of various ways this can be implemented in Ubuntu (using Nmcli, nm-connection-editor and netplan).

Comment: Thank you for your answers very much. Something came up at work, and i couldn't experiment your answer. As soon as i will have time, i will try it and i will accept this as an answer. I hope this will work without any Vlan configuration requirement on Ubuntu.

Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 1):

**Working Solution :**

It did worked for my situation, without **vlan_filtering** option is enabled, as **user1686** stated below, but i will keep the solution as it is, for the reason being, if someone who may need to use it for other ranges of VLAN's.

```
ip link add br0 up type bridge vlan_filtering 1
ip link set eth0 master br0
ip link set eth1 master br0
bridge vlan add vid 2-4094 dev br0 self
bridge vlan add vid 2-4094 dev eth0 master
bridge vlan add vid 2-4094 dev eth1 master
```

To enable Spanning Tree Protocol

```
brctl stp br0 on
```

If you want to make the interface reachable between Ubuntu and the Switches

```
ip link add link br0 name Vlan90 up type vlan id 90
ip addr add 10.200.10.3/28 dev Vlan90
```

Ifconfig screen after all configuration

[image]

Comment: If you're adding all possible VLANs, then just don't enable vlan_filtering at all. You'll get the same result in a simpler way (and without the extra CPU usage).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will check it out, when i will have time.

Comment: It worked without enabling vlan_filtering. Thank you!